# Como centrar la card segunda columna de el grid

Tags: grid

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)
.grid-cards
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
    grid-template-areas: 'item1 item2' '.item3'

.item
    &:nth-child(1)
        grid-area: item1

    &:nth-child(2)
        grid-area: item2

    &:nth-child(3)
        grid-area: item3
        grid-column-start: 2
        grid-column-end: -1
```

quiero sentrar el item3 ya que solo tengo 3 cards pero cuando paso la tercer card a la segunda fila solo la puedo ubicar a la derecha o a la izquierda, como podria hacer para que unicamente esa quede centrada?

Comment: No se entiende como exactamente debe quedar el tercer item

Comment: Si el tercer item debe tomar todo el ancho, como segunda fila (`row`), faltaría agregar más declaraciones

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que corregir la declaración del área; deben ser sin puntos y todos entre una misma comillas, quedando asi:

```
grid-template-areas: 'item1 item2 item3'
```

Luego hay que agregar una declaración de filas (`rows`) del mismo modo que la columna:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)
```

Luego de esto, al tercer `item` se le declara que ocupe una columna completa, y que se ubique como segunda fila.

```
grid-column: 1/3 /* ocupa una columna de entre los tres ítems */
grid-row: 2/3 /* ocupa la segunda fila de entre los tres ítems */
```

Éste es la demostración según yo entendí la pregunta:

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.grid-cards {
  display: grid;
  gap: .50rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'item1 item2 item3';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .50rem
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  
  &:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: item1
  }
  
  &:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: item2
  }
  
  &:nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: item3;
    grid-column: 1/3; /* abarca 1 columna de tres items */
    grid-row: 2/3; /* abarca la segunda fila de tres items */
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="grid-cards">
  <div class="item">Uno</div>
  <div class="item">Dos</div>
  <div class="item">Tres</div>
</div>
```